# How to refresh Spring JPA when data is updated from querydsl directly?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm using spring data jpa and querydsl. I don't want to update directly through JPA because I have to submit a complete entity, which introduces an unnecessary query. So, I use querydsl instead:

```kotlin
val qRecord = QCoupon.coupon
jpaQueryFactory.update(qRecord)
    .set(qRecord.useState, Coupon.STATE_ORDERED)
    .set(qRecord.useTime, useTime)
    .where(qRecord.id.eq(recordId))
    .execute()
```

But the query after that in the same transcation cannot get the latest data, I think it has something to do with the first-level cache.

Adding `@Modifying` doesn't work because I didn't use `@Query`, the first annotation will be ignored.

*I know `EntityManager.clear()` can fix that. But it looks too heavy, I'm not sure this is a good idea.*

> [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825429/spring-data-refresh-entity-after-manual-backend-query-update) explained the cause of the problem very well but not my case -- I have rejected both two answers.
>
> 1. `@Modifying` is ignored.
> 2. `EntityManager.clear()` looks too heavy, and `find()` also need an entity.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the entity? ```entityManager.refresh(entityManager.find(Coupon.class, recordId))```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring data - Refresh entity after "manual" backend query update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825429/spring-data-refresh-entity-after-manual-backend-query-update)

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling Good, it works. Pls put your idea to answer area so that I can accept it.

Comment: @JensSchauder I have read that post and its related post. They explained the cause of the problem very well, but unfortunately, it was not suitable for my usecase. Thank you all the same.

Comment: The question even describes the usage of `refresh` in the question itself, which you claim solves your problem.

Comment: @JensSchauder Yes. But `refresh` also need a complete entity which I want to avoid (unnecessary query). @Jan-Willem Gmelig Meyling's suggestion give me another choice: `em.find()` will not look up the entire table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling 's idea. Because he didn't reply to me, I wrote it in my answer.

> Have you tried refreshing the entity?
> `entityManager.refresh(entityManager.find(Coupon.class, recordId))`

`em.find()` will not look up the entire table, that's what I want.